# how to publish a topic from kinect in a node?

Tags: ros, kinect, rosbag, topic-tools, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish 3 topics from pr2, one from kinect and one from point_cloud (kinect) in a single node and then save the data to disk

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9172/how-to-publish-a-topic-from-kinect-in-a-node?/) by [Monica](https://answers.ros.org/users/172/monica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you didn't leave very many details, so I'm going to do my best to parse your request one step at a time:

- Publish 3 topics from pr2

Well, this one is the hardest.  I'm not sure if you have an actual PR2 or you would like to run one in simulation.  Please clarify, and I'll do my best to update this answer accordingly.  For now, I'm going to assume you have your PR2 running and you can rostopic list/rostopic echo the 3 topics you'd like just fine.

- One from kinect and one from point_cloud kinect

So when you run the [openni_camera driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera), it will publish the RGB image data from the kinect, as well as the depth data in PointCloud2.  These should be published as */camera/rgb/image_color* and */camera/depth/points2* respectively.

- Then save the data to disk

Okay, so the final step to saving all of your topics to disk would be to use [rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag) to record a bag of these 5 topics you'd like.  The [command line information for rosbag record](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#record) will show you how to record your topics, but it should go something like this:

*rosbag record /camera/rgb/image_color /camera/depth/points **[YOUR PR2 TOPICS HERE]***

This will record those 5 topics (and those 5 topics only, use *rosbag record -a* to record ALL topics currently published) to a .bag file in your current directory.  Warning, since this has a camera recording, these bag files will easily reach multi-gig size if you leave it running.  To playback this bagfile as topics later, just use *rosbag play /home/monica/my_recorded_bag_directory/my_pr2_kinect_logs.bag*.  You may also want to check out [rosbag compress](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#compress) if your bag file grows too large.

If I misinterpreted any of your requests please let me know; and please try to give a more detailed request in the future.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-24**:
Probably want to add: you will want to run the rosbag command whereever the most data is being produced in order to minimize any network overhead.  You may, in fact, want to run separate rosbag commands, each run on the computer where the data is being produced.